# SSH add key to known_hosts from ssh-keyscan

Tags: ssh, openssh

I keep a local git repo at a remote host `gitserver` deployed to my LAN. When I am away from home I have to access that server through the LAN's external IP. (The router does not offer loopback).

At home my LAN DNS resolves `gitserver` to the LAN address but when I'm away, I put `gitserver` to my `/etc/hosts` file as the external IP of the LAN.

This works well enough for me but I get a warning that the external IP is not in the known_hosts file.

I'm trying to add that key using ssh-keyscan

```
ssh-keyscan -p 4444 -t ecdsa 100.101.102.103
```

I get a result like :

```
[100.101.102.103]:4444 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <GOBBLEDEEGOOKalphanumericstring>
```

I want to update my `known_hosts` file with that key but the `known_hosts` file expects what I suspect is a hostID key. For example:

```
|1|SoMeThing=|AnotherThing= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 = ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <GOBBLEDEEGOOKalphanumericstring>
```

How do I find the `SoMeThing...` part -- the HostID? -- of the `known_hosts` entry?

Comment: Appending output of ssh-keyscan to known_hosts file works for me `ssh-keyscan somdomain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You might get a conflict if same ip exists more than one time in know_hosts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|1|b64|b64` format in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is a hashed hostname; see `HashKnownHosts` in [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#HashKnownHosts) and `-H` in [`man 1 ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1#H). Using this format is **optional**; if you *want* it, see `-H` in [`man 1 ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan.1#H)

Note that if anyone intercepts your first connection from a given machine to what you *think* is the correct address (your 100.101.102.103) they can supply a fake key and steal and/or alter the data you send and receive on that machine.

Comment: `ssh-keyscan -H -p 2314 -t ecdsa 100.101.102.103` put exactly what I was looking for. Pasted it into the bottom of known_hosts and mission accomplished.